# How to move the profile page customization from one server to another server?

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, central-administration, backup, mysites

I customized the Mysites OOTB web parts and master page in SharePoint 2013, I need to move our changes to one server to another server which have different domain, It tried exporting and importing web parts, while that process web part title are not working at the same time it's difficult to add the web part manually. If backup Restoration will work for that process?Please suggest some idea for better migration?